# I need to retain the values after refresh on visualforce page. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

When I Press the Save button it saves the values but when I hit F5 or refresh; the values are gone, they are not visible on my VF page.And for this :

- I have created VF page with standard controller and extensions.
- created one controller.
- And I have embedded VF page into Opportunity object.

Any idea how I can achieve this ??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The description is not very clear to me. What my understanding is you have a VF page with Opportunity standard controller with extension class. This page has a form which works when you save, but when whole page is refreshed the values are gone.

If my understanding is correct than here is a solution that you can try. For standard controllers to get data they need record id you can pass it through url like this:

http://na1.salefroce.com/apex/yourVFPage?id=

Now in your extension you can use following method to get the record:

```
public Opportunity opp;

public myControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
    this.opp = (Opportunity)stdController.getRecord();
}
```

Now you have record values in the opp variable, you can use this to display values as long as id parameter is passed. You can populate this variable by using SOQL as well.

Comment: Thanks, @SarveshSinghrour for replying..but it's not working like dis way.